# Listening to all scroll events on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background:**

I'm writing a component that opens up a sub-menu on click. I can't know where this component will be placed on the page or how far it will be nested in areas that may have the `overflow` property set.

Given that the overflow may clip the sub-menu I am instead making the sub-menu itself be attached to the `body` giving it an absolute position and linking it via code to the original component. This takes care of the overflow issue.

**Problem:**

However if a user scrolls the sub-menu remains in place, rather than moving with its linked component, **so I need to be able to listen to any and all scroll events that occur on the page** so I can reposition the sub-menu appropriately.

If there's an easy way to listen to all scroll events or if there's another better way to do this component I would appreciate any input.

I've played around with JSFiddle and set up a [sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/wAadt/) but I haven't had any success nor have I found an answer on this site or anywhere else for that matter; though perhaps I was using the wrong search terms, I can't imagine that I'm the first to have this question.

***EDIT***

To address the close vote, I'm not asking help to debug an issue without providing code nor am I asking something that won't help anyone in the future. I'm asking how I would go about listening to all event of a certain type not matter where the may occur, which I find globally applicable, though perhaps that's subjective.

***EDIT***

`$(window).on('scroll', function(){ /**/ });`
is not an option as it only listens to the window scroll, not any nested scrolls.

`$('#ex1 #ex2').on('scroll', function(){ /**/ });` is not an option as it requires the person who is implementing the code to  be aware of any current or possible future areas on the page that may scroll.

Comment: Please post the relevant code **in the question**. Linking to a fiddle is not enough.

Comment: You might find you can do with with CSS rather than muck about with positioning using JS

Comment: Just bind the scroll event directly to the parents that have the `overflow: scroll` style applied.

Comment: @Popnoodles, there isn't really _relevant code_ as I'm not sure what it would be -- that's my question. The JSFiddle is there to provide a visual to better understand the nested overflows that the page could have.

Comment: The code you added the to fiddle is all relevant. That should be posted in the question. jsfiddle may disappear leaving this question completely useless to future readers. There is a page on S.O. explaining this, I don't know where it is but I know it doesn't like just having links to code.

Comment: @Joe, while that is a possibility it requires the person implementing the component to be aware of every single element on the page that could scroll (which may change by the way given the dynamic layout of a page) which is why I would think it'd be easier maintained by listening to any scroll event.

Comment: @Popnoodles. I've added it, though I truly don't see the benefit since the question is what's relevant and the code is what I'm asking for -- the question does not rely on any proprietary code I've written or placed in the JSFiddle, but I digress.

Comment: You could use `*` but that's not specific at all. Could you add in the code you currently use to show the sub menu?

Comment: @Johannes ~ what Joe states is the most optimal way to listen for targeted scroll events, and would not require the implementer to known anything. You just need to code you sub-menu to rebind/remove it's events when/if it is ever placed/snapped to another element. Your widget just needs to provide an API call to allow for moving it to another element.

Comment: @Johannes consider updating your answer selection to the one I added below (which is now the highest rated). It is unequivocally the best answer possible, as it relies on the simple, standard `capture` argument you can pass when event listening, and is supported across all major browsers.

Comment: @csuwldcat Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I rarely review these older questions. I've evaluated your answer and do think it's cleaner and does what it needs to so I've gone ahead an accepted it.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You should be able to attach a document-level listener with a third parameter of `true` to capture the scroll events on all elements. Here's what that looks like:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ }, true);
```

The `true` at the end is the important part, it tells the browser to capture the event on dispatch, even if that event does not normally bubble, like change, focus, and scroll.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/sayejefobe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 100 times, thanks!

Comment: I've updated the example to demo multiple/nested areas and simplified the console logging, just so it's clear it works as intended: http://jsbin.com/bexuhoyogu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: The true parameter is actually the main thing! Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to remove the event listener, you have to add `true` at the end of the call again: `document.removeEventListener('scroll', function(e){ }, true);` See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 2):

You need to see whether scroll is happening to window level or to an element level. Usually in your case '*' should suffice.

```
$('*').scroll(function() {
    alert('scroll');
});
```

Here is updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/wAadt/1

Answer (score 2):

How about listing on all elements and the window?

```
$('*').add(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log('scroll');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it would be to find out which elements are scrollable, then attach listeners to them. You could run this function on any page change to make sure you've always got all the scrollables.

This is a benefit over using listeners on every element (as the other solutions would do) in terms of performance: every time the page updates so do the listeners. With lots, this quickly affects performance and memory use.

The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtOfCode/wAadt/8/

The code:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    if($(this).css("overflow") == "auto" || $(this).css("overflow") == "scroll") {
        $(this).scroll(function() {
            console.log("scroll");
        });
    }
});
```

*(thanks to @pebbl for the help)*

You could then wrap this in a function and run it on change:

```
function addListeners() {
    $("*").each(function() {
        if($(this).css("overflow") == "auto" || $(this).css("overflow") == "scroll") {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red').scroll(function() {
                console.log("scroll");
            });
        }
    });
}

$("body").on("change",function()
    addListeners();
}
```

Admittedly it is a bit convoluted but it addresses the issue with as few event listeners as possible.

Comment: Your method is not doing what you expect. It is actually binding a scroll listener to every element on the page.

Comment: I've just had another look and [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtOfCode/wAadt/4/) to show where the listeners are; check it again. Only the scrollable elements have listeners, not, for example, all the `<p>`s.

Comment: You're conditional if statement is fine for filtering by, but that is not what is getting used as the context for the `.scroll()`. Check this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wAadt/5/) and you will see. Basically the `$(this).add()` construction makes no sense at all ([there is no version that accepts no arguments](http://api.jquery.com/add/)), and what you have filtered will never get back to the original `$().scroll()`. You'd be far better off using what you have as part of a `.filter()` call.

Comment: Allow me to refer you back to my second updated fiddle in the comment as proof. It applies an event listener and an attribute of listened=true to each element that matches the selection; on inspecting these in dev tools it is apparent that it is only the scrollable elements selected. Whether it is syntactically correct or not, it does what I said it would do.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't — see below for a fiddle version that does work (I've added the border to show visibly what is getting selected). As I said, your filter is fine, & yes you are applying your attributes in there (so they appear to work), but you are actually applying `.scroll()` to `$($('*'))` not the filtered elements, that is why I have brought the `.scroll()` inside your filtered section. http://jsfiddle.net/wAadt/7/. If you check my previous fiddle you will see that bringing your attributes down to where you are applying `.scroll()` means that every element gets the attribute applied.

Comment: Ah right, I see it. Sorry - seemed to work to me because it was applying attributes in the right place. Thanks, I'll edit the original.