# Can an element with overflow: scroll bubble to document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to add scroll listener to an element that has `overflow-y: scroll`

Adding listener to window does not work. If you have an element:

`<div id='my-div'>my div</div>`

with style:

```
#my-div {
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

the following JavaScript will not fire when scrolling inside of the div:

```
window
  .addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('do something on scroll')
  })
```

It appears this is because bubbling does not occur on scroll events for performance considerations.

Instead it is recommended that you attach the scroll event directly:

```
document
  .getElementById('my-div')
  .addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log('do something on scroll')
  })
```

But this can be problematic from the standpoint of having to pass references to elements around an application. In my application (which is using React, though this applies equally to any application using the W3C document spec), there are several layers of nesting in order to get a reference to the element with `overflow` set. Is there a way to avoid having to pass references around?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be as simple as adding a `true` for the third argument of `addEventListener` to capture events from all Elements. Like:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ }, true);
```

There's another questions that addresses this problem in more detail: [Listening to all scroll events on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270036/listening-to-all-scroll-events-on-a-page)